# Excel проверка значения ячейки на шаблон

Tags: c#

```
string line6 = excelSheet.Cells[j, 6].Value.ToString(); // получаю значение из Excel 
char[] charArray = line6.ToCharArray(); // преобразование строки в массив символов
```

Символы могут быть разными. Пробелы могут быть тоже. Мне нужно проверить является ли каждый символ в массиве числом.

Если преобразовать каждый символ в int32 то я могу получить исключение,т.к. могут быть не числа. Подскажите как мне правильно проверить строку.
   Решение на powershell. Может не совсем красиво и с ошибками,но задачу решает.

```
elseif ($Length6 -eq 14) {
$split=$Column6 -split "(.)" -ne ""
for($i=0; $i -le $Length6; $i++){[System.Convert]::ToInt32($split[$i])}
if($split[0] -eq "+" -and $split[1] -eq "7" -and $split[2] -eq "(" и т.д.){
$check++
}
}
```

Comment: У меня тут нескромный вопрос возник: а какое ещё число Вы можете загнать в один символ? Для чего вообще эта проверка? Если символ и является числом, то только цифрой 0..9

Comment: Согласен)Нужно проверить является ли символ числом вообще. Отдельные проверки является ли определённым числом.

Comment: К последней редакции вопроса: `bool allDigits = line6.All(char.IsDigit);`

Comment: Я проверяю к примеру. +7(910)9517202. Условия: 1-й символ "+" ,2-й "7" ,3-й "("  ,7-й ")" и длинна 14 символов. Значит забито правильно.

Comment: Как проверить  является ли 2-й символ цифрой 7

Comment: А теперь ещё раз прочитайте, что Вы написали в вопросе: это же совсем разные вещи :D По сути, Вы хотите сверить строку с определённой маской. Либо regex, либо вручную проверить символы 0, 2 и 6, а все остальные уже вместе сверить на предмет того, являются ли они цифрами

Comment: `bool isPhone = line6[0] == '+' && line6[2] == '(' && line6[6] == ')' && line6.Where((x, i) => i != 0 && i != 2 && i != 6).All(char.IsDigit);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Ответ был дан Kir_Antipov. Спасибо тебе огромное за помощь.По аналогии сделаю для остальных шаблонов.
bool isPhone = line6[0] == '+' && line6[2] == '(' && line6[6] == ')' &&    line6.Where((x, i) => i != 0 && i != 2 && i != 6).All(char.IsDigit);
```